# Is quotes needed for parameter in Windows Task Scheduler?

Tags: command-line, windows-task-scheduler

When running process in Windows Task Scheduler is quotes needed in parameter?  Which would this be equivalent to if typing in command prompt?

```
\\server\myscript.exe 18 import
```

or

```
\\server\myscript.exe "18" "import"
```

[image]

Comment: Typically I would use   .....      "myscript.exe  18 import"

Comment: Someone else made this process thats why I'm trying to clarify if the quotes have any meaning...

Comment: Quotes around the entire command and parameter string works in my experience.